# Pycharm does not automatically add indent for `for` loop julia

Tags: pycharm, julia

When I press `enter` after a `for` loop, Pycharm does not automatically add indent in the next line, I double checked that the indention setting is correct in the code style section and I have no syntax error in my code

Additionally by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+L` to `Reformat Code` nothing happened to line indention

What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: are you sure your editor is setup for Julia? you may have to save the file as a .jl so the correct language is used. Or install a plugin for Julia ?

Comment: Yes, I installed julia and file extension is .jl

Comment: I think you should report bug to https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-intellij. This plugin is unfortunately not being very actively developed. 
It is highly adviced to use VS Code with julia plugin, which is much more maintained and actively developed. 
I have personally left pycharm for VS Code for julia programming because the difference in usage if enormous.